# WinAPI CreateFileA error code 0xdf

Tags: winapi, webdav, createfile, error-code

I have a mapped Webdav Drive and i can't open file for reading using

```
CreateFileA(file_path, FILE_READ_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

i am still getting error code 0xdf

> ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE 223 (0xDF) The file size exceeds the limit
>   allowed and cannot be saved.

but on diskdrive (NTFS) i can read it, but on mapped drive represents as (FAT) a i can just write file

```
CreateFileA(dest_file_path, FILE_WRITE_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

it works

but not reading not, when the file size exceed for example 70 MB

my webdav is running on apache.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

That was a probliem with WebClient Service paramater FileSizeLimitInBytes

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\FileSizeLimitInBytes
```

that was set to 50,000,000 Bytes 50MB

If i set it to

> 0xffffffff

is now possible handle with 4GB files.

Answer (score 1):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\FileSizeLimitInBytes

it should be working